# Matching words as separate strings unless they start with a capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regexp

```
/[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+/g
```

that matches 'words' composed by characters of unlimited lenght.

If I do want to exclude words starting with a capital letter?

I tried

```
/(^[A-Z])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+/g
```

but it doesn't seems to work. Can't use things like /w for it doesn't include diacritics.

EDIT: the language in use is Typescript so the javascript engine (which doesn't allow lookbehind, for example) Sorry for not mention this.

EDIT: the input given can be something like

```
"foo"            //should match foo and return true
"Foo"            //should not match foo and return false
"fòo"            //should match fòo and return true
" "              //should not match foo and return false
"."              //should not match foo and return false
","              //should not match foo and return false
```

Code (Typescript) matching without the capital letter thing

```
isProperWord(word){
    /* rejects
      - string that are not words (symbols, spaces, etc...)
      - names (words starting with a capital letter)
    */
    if(word.match(/[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]+/g)){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: What are the word boundaries here? Any char other than `[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]`? Or whitespace and start/end of string?

Comment: Is the pattern to be used in Objective-C / Swift? Or JS? Or PHP? This is important.

Comment: Edited the question. Yes the boundaries should be anything that is not in that character set, so spaces, dots, commas and so on.

Comment: Are you extracting the words? Is the expected result an array of these words?

Comment: No, I need only to know if matches or not, in order to decide if the input is a word, respecting the conditions imposed (only chars, no capital letter at beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all capital letters from your initial range, you may use `[A-ZÀ-ÖØ-Þ]` character class. To match all lowercase letters, `[a-zß-öø-ÿ]`. Note that `×` and `÷` are not letters, I removed them from these classes.

To make sure the whole string consists of these letters only, and the first char is not an uppercase letter, use

```
/^[a-zß-öø-ÿ][A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Y95jn/2).

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['foo','fòo','Foo',' ','.',','];
var rx = /^[a-zß-öø-ÿ][A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s,"=>",rx.test(s));
}
```

To extract words, use custom boundaries:

```js
var s = 'foo,fòo,Foo';
var rx = /(?:[^A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]|^)([a-zß-öø-ÿ][A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*)(?![A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ])/g;
var m, res=[];
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't notice that symbols. Tricky! Thank you very much. As I was asking to triplee how can I do the same thing with multiple words ("foo1 foo2" matches foo1 AND foo2 "Foo1, foo2. foo3" matches foo2 and foo3)? It is not really necessary, only curiosity

Answer (score 3):

The expression `^[A-Z]` means match an uppercase character at the beginning of line.  You probably tried to type `[^A-Z]` which matches a character which is not an uppercase alphabetic between A and Z, but that still doesn't help, because the regex engine will find a character somewhere which matches this, and be satisified. (For example, a space trivially matches this -- it's a character, and it's not in the range A through Z.)

If you use a regex dialect which understands word boundaries with `\b`, try

```
/\b[a-z][A-Za-z]*/
```

to match a token which has a word boundary on its left, and a lowercase character adjacent to it. (I am ignoring your locale extension, which is not portable and possibly not well-defined.)

In isolation, the `/g` flag doesn't do anything.  If you have a language which supports it, and use a regex in a `while` loop or similar, it will cause the engine to return all the matches in the string, one at a time, inside the loop; but without further context, we have no idea whether that is actually true here.

Comment: This answer should hopefully also help illustrate why it is *imperative* that you define which regex dialect and/or host language you are using. Maybe [edit] your question to update it with this information.

Comment: Good points! Thank you it works! May I ask how to do the same thing with multiple words ("foo1 foo2" matches foo1 AND foo2 "Foo1 foo2 foo3" matches foo2 and foo3)?

Comment: Add `(?:\s+\w+)*` to match multiple arbitrary words, or perhaps `( [a-z][A-Za-z]+)*` to match multiple words which all begin with lowercase. It's still not clear whether you are using a tool which supports `\s` and `\w` so YMMV.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include all infos. Thank you! :)